# How to auto break line when content is too long in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

There is some text comprised of 200 characters. I need to show only the first 100 characters and 100 another characters should show new line. How to implement it using jquery?

```
<div>
<p id="msg">The content (length > 200)</p>
</div>





<script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function () {
                                    var txt = $('#msg').text();
                                    for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i = i+20) {
                                        $('#msg').text(txt.substring(i,i+20) + '\n');
                                    }
                                })
                </script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5frjxqxu/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert **'\n'** as 101 character into string with [String.protype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), see code sample for that:

```js
$(function () {
var longLine = '123flml;mdskl;fmvfmxlkvmefkldmkp[welr[plkewrpojmgkrmbperkgopmikgfmnprtm,gionrtbjnkbtmriogntrjongmkotrmgiotnrgnmtrkogmpiotrmgomntrm';
  $(msg).text(longLine.slice(0,100) + '\n' + longLine.slice(100));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p id="msg">The content (length > 200)</p>
</div>
```